# I want to attach the contents of ELK's kibana dashboard to the openstack horizon dashboard

Tags: kibana, openstack, horizon

I want to attach the contents of ELK's Kibana dashboard to the Openstack Horizon dashboard

[image: like this.]

is it possible? If it is possible, I want to know how to implement it

If that is not possible, I want to know how to graph Elasticsearch's log graphically on the Horizon dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to take the contents of Kibana and show them in Openstack Horizon. On the other hand you can connect your Openstack Horizon to ElasticSearch.
You should check this [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/searchlight/architecture.html) to find out how to integrate openstack with elasticsearch.